# c# javascript in browser

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox, browser, firebug

I am trying to automatically click on a button on a webpage. An example of the button can be found here:  http://www.movshare.net/video/ut55cfdvg5wgj/?

I can get rid of it with javascript in firefox usin firebug, but when I'm trying the same script in c# with the browser controll it doesn't work.

The script is:

```
btn = document.getElementsByName("submit"); 
btn[0].click();
```

Any help would be nice.

Comment: can you post your c# code please ?

Comment: or at least the HTML output that contains your button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.click` would refer to the corresponding event, try;

```
.Document.All.GetElementsByName("submit")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: The code above is javascript, not c#. the `.click();` seems to be a function as it works fine with firebug and triggers the click-event.

Comment: Got it to work now, haven't tried with the `.All` there before.
Thanks.